# TabView Fragment not Refresh after callback from another Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have set up `RecyclerView` in the `Fragments` of `TabView`.The Recylerview data is set using `RestApi`.When one item in `Tab2` is deleted,the item need to be added in `Tab3` by calling RestApi.`Tab2` contain a list of Inactive members.`Tab3` contain a list of Active members.After a member is activated from `Tab2`, a `RestApi` should be call to update a list of `Tab3`.
This is code for callback interface in Tab2`

```
  OnTableAddedListener tlistener;
 public interface OnTableAddedListener
    {
        void addTable();
    }
```

This callback is called after member Activated as

```
public void removeItem(int position)
    {
        current.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position,current.size());
        if(tlistener!=null){
            tlistener.addMember);
}
    }
```

I have implemented the callback interface in `Tab3`.This is called in `Tab3` after member activated and need to add in Active members by calling `RestApi` and new data.

```
  @Override
    public void addTable() {
        getData();
        FreeTable table=new FreeTable();
        tx=fm.beginTransaction();
        tx.detach(table);
        tx.attach(table);
        tx.commit();

    }
```

But `Fragment` is not Refresh ?How to resolve this ?
This is code for ViewPager to add Tabs

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_tab, container, false);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            tabLayout=(TabLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
            viewPager=(ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.simpleViewPager);
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Total Members"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Inactive Member"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Active Member"));
              // tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Auto Suggest"));
              // PagerAdapter adapter=new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        PagerAdapter adapter=new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        //PagerAdapter adapter=new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: where are you assigning your listener

Comment: where to asign ?

Comment: post your code where you add tabs to your tabview